# Can't pass a State from parent Component to Child (pomodoro clock state counter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm a React Newbie and i'm trying to build a Pomodoro Clock. I'm Actually Stuck trying to make the buttons + and - changing the numbers i have set on my State. 
In my Main App Component i have:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      breakValue: 5,
      sessionValue: 25
    }
```

Now i'm trying to pass to the SetTimer component (which will handle those buttons + and -) the state to update the numbers:
so i've created this function to pass the state(that is an example to handle the + button):

```
handleUpdate = value => this.setState({
    breakValue : value+1,
    sessionValue: value+1
  })
```

I passed the function as props inside the child component.
This is the SetTimer child component with the props inside the render method in App:

```
<SetTimer handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate}  id="break" type= "Break" value={this.state.breakValue}
```

After that i went inside the SetTimer component and i created another function passing the value parameter props:

```
class SetTimer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    click(){
        this.props.handleUpdate(this.props.value)

    }
```

And i passed the function Onclick to the button tag:

```
<button onClick={this.click}
```

The compiler is telling me that they can't read the props of Undefined inside click function. I've used this methos to pass state between parents to child and it always worked. What i'm missing here ?thank you very much guys for any help

Comment: try adding `this.click.bind(this)` to your button onClick

Comment: try `<button onClick={this.click.bind(this} ... />`

Comment: alternatively, make click an arrow function, like so: `click = () => this.props.handleUpdate(this.props.value)`. Read more about this here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing props correctly but reading them incorrectly.

Let's understand what does following code do?

```js
<button onClick={this.click} ... />
```

This adds the click event on a button with handler associated with it. As we know, every programming language runs a code block in a specific scope/context. For this function it will be document's scope/context by default.

To use props we need context of the class component `SetTimer`.

There are two ways,

1. Pass the context in which you are executing the `onClick`.

```js
<button onClick={this.click}
```

2. Make click function as arrow function so it won't accept any context and always run in the component's scope.

```js
click = () => {
  this.props.handleUpdate(this.props.value)
}
```